# Failed to find Java VM

Tags: java

I've always used Google2SRT, a light software to download subtitles from Youtube. Now it no longer works: "Startup Error: Failed to find Java VM".

I have Java installed, I have Netbeans installed and working, I have never had any Java related issues.

I've tried reinstalling everything, I've tried creating a JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME System variable and pointing it to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191" according to this tutorial: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

It felt odd because I didn't even had this environment variable previously. I have no idea what's the issue.

I've tried uninstalling Netbeans and other programming tools as well.

I'm on Windows 7 x64.

---

`java -debug -version > "%userprofile%\desktop\javaDebug.log" 2>&1` returns:

java version "1.8.0_191"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

---

I have also tried setting maximum heap size in _JAVA_OPTIONS

[System Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su0T8.png)

Comment: have you tried `java` and `javac` in cli?

Comment: @Deadpool `java` returns all that jazz, but `javac` is not recognized as a command. Does that mean anything?

Comment: Yes, JAVA_HOME is sufficient and add it to path , check any youtube video how to set java path

Comment: @Deadpool I had already done that from the start. Is there a way to certify I did it correctly? Edit: Oh, when I pass `java -agentpath` I get "Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine."

Comment: You should contact the google2srt project for technical support for that software. It seems the issue is really with google2srt, not with Java, and therefore this question is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 5):

Just go to the install dir (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Google2SRT), open a cmd.exe, cd to the above folder and type java -jar Google2SRT.jar. You don't need the .exe

This should work, provided you have java installed. Check by typing java -version in the cmd.

Comment: I just normally opened jar file instead of the exe file and finally changed the shortcut target from exe to jar file